Compress selective rows in Oracle (19c)
I have a requirement to compress selective rows in Oracle. I wanted to see if it is possible.
So far I have read it is not possible (except workaround).

I cant do a CTAS. My table size is of 2 T.B.
Cant create a new column ; database storage is at max
Some tables have regular column without LOB. Some have CLOB and some have BLOB.


You might want to rephrase the question and focus on your root problem, instead of asking for help with a specific solution. I could answer the question with a solution involving partitioning, which would allow compressing some partitions and not others. But changing your tables to partitioned tables would require a lot of initial space, which wouldn't work if your database storage is maxed out. If all you care about is saving space, start with the smallest indexes and tables (based on DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES), compress them to save initial space, then use that space to rebuild larger objects.

You can absolutely compress certain rows, though not by a row-by-row command or attribute (you can't compress an existing row in place, only on load or reorg/segment move).
When non-advanced (non-OLTP) compression is enabled, whether Basic or HCC (Exadata), the compression attribute only has an effect on new rows, and then only on certain conditions:

Basic compression is only applied to direct path INSERT SELECT (e.g. requiring the APPEND hint or PDML mode). It does not apply to rows inserted conventionally.

HCC compression also originally applied only to direct path inserts. However in recent versions (19c?) any array insert, even if not direct (no APPEND hint), can be HCC compressed. INSERT VALUES however will not be. You can leverage this to intentionally load some rows compressed and others not.

Neither compression setting says anything about existing rows already in the table. This permits several interesting strategies:
3a. Use direct path bulk insert or CTAS with compression enabled on historical/old data that is relatively inactive, then disable compression and insert newer/active rows on top. The newer/active rows will be uncompressed while the older rows will be compressed, which is a common pattern to save space without impacting performance for either application insert or update of recent/active rows.
3b. Compress an existing table (alter table ... move compress ...), then set its compression off so that any new rows arriving in the future will be uncompressed. This is also a common pattern to save space without impacting application insert performance.
3c. Partition the table (typically by date) so that older partitions can be compressed with an alter table move partition ... compress command, leaving newer partitions uncompressed. This is a lot easier to manage than #3a and #3b and accomplishes the same goal. Given that your particular table is 2TB, it sounds like you really need to be using partitioning for multiple reasons.

As you mentioned LOBs, be aware that while Oracle does support LOB compression it is an extra cost option (requiring the expensive ACO license), so unless you know for a fact your company has ACO licenses to cover your database, do not use it. The only other option for compressing LOB data that some folks have used is to convert CLOB to BLOB (dbms_lob.converttoblob) and use utl_compress.lz_compress to compress it in binary when storing it, then uncompress it (utl_compress.lz_uncompress) and reconvert to CLOB (dbms_lob.converttoclob) on query, perhaps in a view. This is rather complex/unwieldy but does work if space is at a premium, LOBs are a significant portion of your usage and you don't have the ACO license.


So as you can see, there are various ways to have some rows compressed and some not. In fact, in Exadata in the same table you can have a mixture of all four HCC types, Basic, Advanced/OLTP, and uncompressed. Unfortunately the data dictionary will not tell you what the compression state of your table is, only what rule will be applied to new data coming in or on a move. To find out the current compression breakdown of rows in a table, you have to actually query the table and use the dbms_compression.get_compression_type function.
